# What's the difference between alias and label in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using label:

```
    func.generate_series(
        start_date,
        end_date,
        interval,
    ).label('generated_interval_start')
```

Using alias:

```
    func.generate_series(
        start_date,
        end_date,
        interval,
    ).alias('generated_interval_start') # works as well
```

I don't see any difference from the practical point

Comment: The second form raises an error, so there's that.  More seriously, labels are for columns, aliases are for tables, just like in SQL. Note that `generate_series` can return more than one row, making it "table-like".